# Remove package from apt update list

Tags: apt, debian-bookworm

I'm fairly new to linux operations. In an effort to install mysql 8, I downloaded a package, and used `dpkg -i` to install, per a tutorial I was reviewing.

Once complete, I did `apt update` and have gotten the following error:

> `Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bookworm InRelease The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ###hash###`

Then it pops up the following error:

> `E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.`

I've tried editing source, but there are only Debian URLs/domains in that file. I've checked `/var/lib/apt/lists` and I don't see anything related this mysql package. I've tried `apt remove` but it can't find the package anywhere. I also tried `dkpg -r` and it says it can't find anything installed.

So, it looks like I have this ghost package that `apt update` is trying to use, but is failing due to it being unsigned (even though I can see a signature at the link).

Any help on where to look for this package the my system doesn't acknowledge or how to remove it from that `apt update` list would be helpful.

Edit:
The package I'm working with is: `mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb`

Comment: If you have the Synaptic package manager, which provides a nice GUI, it easy to find a package and uninstall it. See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkgtools.en.html, https://wiki.debian.org/Synaptic

Comment: Out of curiosity - do you need that specific version? If not - you could potentially just use apt install mysql-server and get the latest version as per documentation in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install

Comment: Thanks, @Darius. When I try that, I get: `E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate`.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I'm using this on a webserver, and I don't have a GUI/desktop installed.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is really dumb, and I apologize. I got it removed by doing the following:

`dpkg -r mysql-apt-config`

I tried multiple times doing something similar, but I always added a * character, so I didn't have to write the whole thing out, as is shown in the edit. What I was using was, `dpkg -r mysql-apt*`. This gave me output saying I needed to reference the package, not the file.

After listing everything out with `dpkg -l`, I found the package name was simply `mysql-apt-config`. Once I removed the asterisk, it went through without an issue.

Now when I use `apt update`, I'm getting no errors and that package is no longer showing in list of packages to update.